# How to tell the target interfaceOrientation in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uikit, uiinterfaceorientation

Since `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated in iOS 8 (and we should use `- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator`), how do I know the interfaceOrientation the user is going to rotate?

Yes, I could read the size value to know proportions, but it doesn't tell me the difference between `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` and `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you rightly say, you are receiving this event:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size 
    withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator)
```

The second parameter is a transition coordinator. Use it! It has a `targetTransform` property that tells you what's about to happen.

Comment: Thanks Matt (btw I'm a fan of your work). So, now there's no easy way to read the UIInterfaceOrientation? You have to calculate it?

Comment: You can read the interface orientation _now_ but your question was "the interfaceOrientation the user is _going_ to rotate?" The most information you get about the _future_ at the time this method is called is from the `targetTransform`.